# Проблема с циклом для DataGridViev в C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть цикл для DataGridViev с последовательным расчетом,необходимо,чтобы сначала он считал по одной формуле определенное кол-во раз,затем один раз по другой и в конце по 3-й формуле тоже определенное кол-во раз
Сейчас это выглядит вот так,но я знаю,что это неверно,подскажите как должно быть

```
               double z_pnd = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text), z_pvd = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text),
                t_kond = Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text), t_dear = Convert.ToDouble(textBox9.Text),
                t_oe = Convert.ToDouble(textBox10.Text), t_egu = Convert.ToDouble(textBox11.Text),
                z = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text), alfa = 0.9, tp_pereddear = t_dear - 10,
                t_nach = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text), p_pg = Convert.ToDouble(textBox7.Text),

              t_pv = ((t_nach - t_kond - t_oe - t_egu) / (z + 1)),
              t_pvopt = t_nach - t_pv,
              t_pvek = alfa * (t_pvopt - t_kond) + t_kond,
              delt_pvd = (t_pvek - t_dear) / z_pvd,
              delt_pnd = (tp_pereddear - t_kond - t_oe - t_egu) / z_pnd;


            textBox15.Text = delt_pvd.ToString();
            textBox16.Text = delt_pnd.ToString();

            int gg = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
            dataGridView2.RowCount = gg;
            double yBasepnd = t_kond + t_oe + t_egu + delt_pnd;
            double yBasepvd = t_kond + t_oe + t_egu + t_pv;
            double[] y = new double[gg];
            for (int i = 0; i < z_pnd; i++)

            {
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = y[i].ToString();
                y[i] = yBasepnd + delt_pnd * i;
            }

            for (int i = z_pnd)  
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = y[i].ToString();
                y[i] = t_dear;
            } 

           for (int i = z_pnd+1; i < gg; i++)
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = y[i].ToString();
                y[i] = yBasepvd + delt_pvd * (i-z_pnd-1);
             }
```

Comment: По вашему отрывку код нельзя сказать точно что вы хотите сделать. Кто считал? Какие формулы?

Comment: z_pnd-кол во раз для расчета по этой формуле: 
y[i] = yBasepnd + delt_pnd * i; 
Затем значение: 
y[i] = t_dear; 
Затем z_pvd- кол-во раз для расчета по формуле 
y[i] = yBasepvd + delt_pvd * (i-z_pnd-1)

Comment: Может быть, все-таки прочитать про циклы в C#?

Comment: Читал,смотрел видео,ничего толкового не выходит,то ошибки,то невозможность преобразования,подобного,что мне нужно я не нашел

Comment: Предлагаю вам взять любой учебник и прочитать основы...так как без понимания таких элементарных вещей нормально программировать вы не сможете.

Comment: Хорошо,последую вашему совету,спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < z_pnd; i++)
{
  y[i] = yBasepnd + delt_pnd * i;
  dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = y[i].ToString();
}

y[i] = t_dear;
dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = y[i].ToString();

for (i = i + 1; i < gg; i++)
{
  y[i] = yBasepvd + delt_pvd * (i-z_pnd-1);
  dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = y[i].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Нельзя преобразовать double в int

Comment: @МихаилК Вот сидите Вы перед компьютером и получаете такую ошибку. Разве не приходит в голову набрать в поисковике: "C# преобразовать double в int"?

Comment: Большое спасибо